# Significant Terms Aggregation of "flat" structures

Tags: elasticsearch, recommendation-engine, significant-terms

I currently try to prototype a product recommendation system using the Elasticsearch Significant Terms aggregation. So far, I didn't find a good example yet which deals with "flat" JSON structures of `sales` (here: The `itemId`) coming from a relational database, such as mine:

Document 1

```
{
    "lineItemId": 1,
    "lineNo": 1,
    "itemId": 1,
    "productId": 1234,
    "userId": 4711,
    "salesQuantity": 2,
    "productPrice": 0.99,
    "salesGross": 1.98,
    "salesTimestamp": 1234567890
}
```

Document 2

```
{
    "lineItemId": 1,
    "lineNo": 2,
    "itemId": 1,
    "productId": 1235,
    "userId": 4711,
    "salesQuantity": 1,
    "productPrice": 5.99,
    "salesGross": 5.99,
    "salesTimestamp": 1234567890
}
```

I have around 1.5 million of these documents in my Elasticsearch index. A `lineItem` is a part of a `sale` (identified by `itemId`), which can consist of 1 or more `lineItems` What I would like to receive is the, say, 5 most uncommonly common products which were bought in conjunction with the sale of one specific `productId`.

The MovieLens example (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_significant_terms_demo.html) deals with data in the structure of

```
{
    "movie": [122,185,231,292,
              316,329,355,356,362,364,370,377,420,
              466,480,520,539,586,588,589,594,616
    ],
    "user": 1
}
```

so it's unfortunately not really useful to me. I'd be very glad for an example or a suggestion using my "flat" structures. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Is your `sale` an `object` or `nested`? In any case, have you already tried the obvious: `{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "sale.productId": 1235
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "most_sig": {
      "significant_terms": {
        "field": "sale.productId",
        "size": 6
      }
    }
  }
}`?

Comment: If `sale` is `object` (thus a flat array of values) it should work as is. If it's `nested` I think  you would need a `"include_in_parent": true` and use the same query.

Comment: @AndreiStefan Thanks a lot for your comments. Unfortunately, the `lineItems` are neiter nested nor in a parent-child object structure. The documents are in one index as described above. I understand I'd need to aggregate based on the `itemId`, because I want the products which have been uncommonly common bought together in one `sale` (`itemId`).

Comment: Something is still not clear: same `itemId` means a bundle of products that have been bought together, right? Bundle of products means different `productId` for the same `itemId`. And given one `productId` you want to find the uncommonly common `productId`s different from the initial `productId` that were bought together. Do I understand this right?

Comment: @AndreiStefan That's remarkably correct :-) Yes!

Comment: Since I don't have the amount of data that you do, try this: **1.** get the  list of `itemId`s for bundles that contain a certain `productId` that you want to find "stuff" for: `{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {"term": {
        "productId": 1234
      }}
    }
  },
  "fields": ["itemId"]
}`.

Comment: Then  **2.** using this list create this query: `GET /sales/sales/_search?search_type=count
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "terms": {
          "itemId": [your_itemIDs_here_separated_by_commas]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "most_sig": {
      "significant_terms": {
        "field": "productId",
        "size": 0
      }
    }
  }
}`

Comment: @AndreiStefan Thanks a lot for your suggestion. I think there is a slight problem because there can be potentially (tens of) thousands of 'itemId's returned from the first query. I think ES has a standard of 1024 terms, but it's configurable: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26642369/max-limit-on-the-number-of-values-i-can-specify-in-the-ids-filter-or-generally-q

Comment: If you can give it a try I'd be curious. Either way, you would need that list of IDs I think.

Comment: Did you get the chance to test this?

Comment: Not yet, sorry... I hope I will have time today.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're trying to build an *item-based recommender*.  [Apache Mahout](https://mahout.apache.org/users/recommender/recommender-documentation.html) has tools to help with collaborative filtering (formerly the Taste project).

There is also a [Taste plugin for Elasticsearch 1.5.x](https://github.com/codelibs/elasticsearch-taste) which I believe can work with data like yours to produce item-based recommendations.

(Note: This plugin uses *Rivers* which were deprecated in Elasticsearch 1.5, so I'd check with the authors about plans to support more recent versions of Elasticsearch before adopting this suggestion.)

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't have the amount of data that you do, try this:

1. get the list of `itemId`s for bundles that contain a certain `productId` that you want to find "stuff" for:

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "productId": 1234
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "fields": [
    "itemId"
  ]
}
```

Then

2. using this list create this query:

```
GET /sales/sales/_search?search_type=count
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "terms": {
          "itemId": [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,11]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "most_sig": {
      "significant_terms": {
        "field": "productId",
        "size": 0
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you have a doc per order line item. What you want is a single doc per order.  The Order doc should have an array of productIds (or an array of line item objects that each include a productId field).

That way when you query for orders containing product X the sig_terms aggregation should find product Y is found to be uncommonly common in these orders.