# Elastic Search Terms filter. Max terms?

Tags: elasticsearch

Is there any limit on number of terms for terms filter?

For example -

```
{
  "filtered": {
    "query": {
      "match": { "ObjectType": "Invoice" }
    },
    "filter": {          
        "terms" : {
          "InvoiceID" : ["Invoice_101_V1", " Invoice_102_V3", " Invoice_103_V3"]
        }
      }

    }
  }
}
```

I have added terms filter which lists the InvoiceID's. So is there any limit on adding terms in terms filter?

Thanks in advance.

Sameer

Comment: possible duplicate of [Max limit on the number of values I can specify in the ids filter or generally query clause?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26642369/max-limit-on-the-number-of-values-i-can-specify-in-the-ids-filter-or-generally-q)

Answer (score 0):

The max number of terms able to be filtered on is 1024, at least for the Java API. Any amount beyond will throw an Exception.