# Limits of Elasticsearch "terms" query

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a set of documents that contain a company name. Queries are working just fine for names typed by the user. I have a mapping in place that handles lowercase and non ASCII etc.

There is now a requirement to upload a list of company names. Up to 10,000.

Is it reasonable to throw Elasticsearch a `terms` query with 10,000 string values?

Comment: Can you elaborate more on this? What are you trying to achieve? You want to search names of all companies at once? Why not then simply list them? Or do you want to search a particular company from those 10000 companies? In that case, elasticsearch can handle millions of values (So 10000 will be easily searchable).

Comment: I want to find 10,000 named companies out of an index of 100 million.

Comment: I think you will find the answer  [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26642369/max-limit-on-the-number-of-values-i-can-specify-in-the-ids-filter-or-generally-q), you might have to wait few seconds for the results to come back.