# Elasticsearch - set max_clause_count

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a pretty big terms query in elasticsearch, so I get 
`too_many_clauses: maxClauseCount is set to 1024`

I tried increasing it in the elasticsearch.yml by

```
index:
query:
bool:
max_clause_count: 10240
```

and via

```
curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/plastic/_settings" -d '{ "index" : { "max_clause_count" : 10000 } }'
```

but nothing worked. My index is named plastic.

Comment: Did you restart your node?

Comment: `index.query.bool.max_clause_count: 10240` in `elasticsearch.yml` file of each node of the cluster. And, of course, restart the nodes (any change in the config file needs a restart).

Comment: That worked, thanks.

Comment: @Naman what is your question that isn't already answered in this thread?

Comment: @Val None, I just *"wants to reward an existing answer."*

Answer (score 20, accepted):

#### Background

***NOTE:*** The advice given in this answer only applies to versions of Elasticsearch below 5.5. The method described references a property that was eventually removed in 5.5.

> #### Search Settings
>
> The setting `index.query.bool.max_clause_count` has been removed. In order
>   to set the maximum number of boolean clauses
>   `indices.query.bool.max_clause_count` should be used instead.

- [Ref - Breaking changes in 5.0 » Settings changes](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/breaking_50_settings_changes.html)

---

#### Original Answer

Add the following:

```
index.query.bool.max_clause_count: 10240
```

To the file `elasticsearch.yml` on each node of the cluster, then of course, restart the nodes (any change in the config file needs a restart).

Comment: For the ES5, look answer below.

Comment: This property was removed the subsequent releases of ES so this A'er is no longer the proper way to address this change in Elasticsearch 5 and higher.

Comment: As of ES 8, it's deprecated and has no effect: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.9/search-settings.html#search-settings

Answer (score 27):

In Elasticsearch 5, `index.query.bool.max_clause_count` has been deprecated/removed.

Insert in your `elasticsearch.yml` file `indices.query.bool.max_clause_count : n` instead (where n - new supported number of clauses).

**NOTE:** [Here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.0/breaking_50_settings_changes.html#_search_settings) is link to documentation.

Comment: It hasn't been deprecated, it's been removed. Your Elasticsearch instance won't start. At least it happens in 5.2.2

Comment: In ES 5, you want to use `indices.query.bool.max_clause_count: 2500` and restart server.

Comment: As of ES 8, it's deprecated and has no effect: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.9/search-settings.html#search-settings

Answer (score 6):

this can also be achieved by updating configuration inside elasticsearch.yml file (inside config folder of elastic installation)

```
indices.query.bool.max_clause_count: 4096
```

Comment: Note that it was required for me to add a space after colon.

Comment: As of ES 8, it's deprecated and has no effect: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.9/search-settings.html#search-settings

Answer (score 5):

If you're looking to make changes to your cloud `elasticsearch.yml` file in a cloud deployment, see [Add Elasticsearch user settings](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud/current/ec-add-user-settings.html) for the steps to follow to achieve this and the changes you're allowed to make. However, note that there is a limit to the settings you're allowed to change in the cloud deployment.

If you're looking to make changes to your local cluster, you can make the change directly in your `elasticsearch.yml` file located at "**elasticsearch-x.x.x/config/elasticsearch.yml**" by simply adding a line of the required setting to the file. For example, if you want to change `indices.query.bool.max_clause_count` from it's default value of 1024 to 4096, you can add the line **indices.query.bool.max_clause_count: 4096** to your **elasticsearch.yml** file.

Remember that `indices.query.bool.max_clause_count` is 1024 be default, though the `elasticsearch.yml` does explicitly contain a line stating this value, yet it would resort to 1024 being the default value. So the only way to change this value is that you will explicitly add the line "**indices.query.bool.max_clause_count: 4096**". By including this line and specifying your preferred value in your own `elasticsearch.yml` file, you have ultimately modified the value "**indices.query.bool.max_clause_count**" for your cluster.

The following image shows how this line was appended to a sample `elasticsearch.yml` file:

[image]

After adding this line and saving the changes to your `elasticsearch.yml` file, start Elasticsearch, and then Kibana (if you're interacting with ES with Kibana). You can verify your setting by running the command: `GET /_cluster/settings/?include_defaults` in Kibana or `curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/_cluster/settings/?include_defaults"` in your command line. Then, look for `max_clause_count` in the command's output to verify the value of `indices.query.bool.max_clause_count`

Comment: Same article is published in a bit more details here:  https://medium.com/@olamideolajidew/making-cluster-wide-changes-to-elasticsearch-by-modifying-the-elasticsearch-yml-file-a0026bd1b7bf