# How to do a simple edit in elasticsearch.yml in a docker container?

Tags: elasticsearch, docker-compose

I am using `docker-compose` as in https://github.com/davidefiocco/dockerized-elasticsearch-indexer/blob/master/docker-compose.yml to initialize a containerized elasticsearch index.
Now, I would like to set a larger value for `indices.query.bool.max_clause_count` than the default setting using a `elasticsearch.yml` config file (this is to run some heavy queries as in [Elasticsearch - set max_clause_count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40275514/elasticsearch-set-max-clause-count)).

So far I tried to add in the `docker-compose.yml` a volume with:

```
services:
   elasticsearch:
      volumes:
        - ./elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml
```

(and variations thereof) trying to point to a `elasticsearch.yml` file (that I would like to ship with the rest of the files) with the right `max_clause_count` setting, but to no avail.

Can someone point me to the right direction?

Comment: Volumes have two parts: your local directory, and the container directory. You are trying to mount a relative path to a file to an unspecified volume; not sure what you are expecting docker to do there. You might want to read the documentation for docker, docker-compose and the readme for the official elasticsearch docker containers that should explain this pretty well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can mount the host's directory containing the elasticsearch.yml into the container using

```
services:
   elasticsearch:
      volumes:
        - path_to/custom_elasticsearch.yml:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml:ro
```

Comment: How could be this applied to Windows 10? The path and all that stuff

Comment: @chomp The left side of the ':' is the relative location of the path of the yml file. The right side should remain constant.

Comment: Is that `:ro` at the end a typo?

Comment: At the time I wrote the answer, it wasn't a typo. The `:ro` at the end allows for the path to be mounted as read-only.

Answer (score 7):

One workaround to perform that (trivial) modification to `elasticsearch.yml` in the container is to modify directly a relevant Dockerfile with the syntax

```
USER root
RUN echo "indices.query.bool.max_clause_count: 1000000" >> /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml
```

so to append the desired custom value.